# Differentiation

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, calculus

Why is
$$\frac{d}{dt}v^2=2v\frac{dv}{dt},$$
When:
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^2=2x,$$
where $v$ is velocity? I don't understand why the variable $x^2$ has the derivative of $2x$, whereas the variable velocity has that derivative. I need to understand it because Feynman uses it in his proof of conservation of energy, but I have never differentiated variables other than $x$ and $y$ in math.

Comment: because dx/dx=1

Answer (score 2):

It is an application of the Chain Rule.  You have a variable $[v(t)]^{2}$, which can be written as the composition of two functions, $v^{2}=f(v(x))$, where $f(\xi)=\xi^{2}$. Then the chain rule says
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{dv}\frac{dv}{dt}.$$
The ordinary derivative $df/dv=f'(v)=2v$, by the ordinary power rule; and $df/dt$ is, by definition, $d(v^{2})/dt$.  Hence
$$\frac{d}{dt}v^{2}=2v\frac{dv}{dt}.$$